# How to power Arduino pro mini and DFPlayer mini togather with 3.7 V LiPo battery?

Tags: power, arduino-pro-mini, battery

I made a small box containing Arduino Pro Mini , DFPlayer Mini player and a 3.7V LiPo battery. Is it possible to power two devices with 3.7 V Battery? 
What is the best way to save power for longer time performance?

Comment: Just remember that a LiPo has 4.3V when it is full and ~3.0V when it is emty. If you have the 3.3V Arduino, you can connect it as it has an internal voltage regulator. the DFPlayer can work up to 5V. So you can connect both. What do you mean with longer time performance? 1 hour? 1 day? 1 week? Stand By? Power Off? When running? And last question: do you have also speakers connected on it (over the same LiPo?). You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a buck/boost voltage regulator. Those are high efficiency switching regulators, and can either increase or decrease the input voltage. Feed the output of the regulator directly into the Arudino's 5V (or 3.3V) line, bypassing the on-board voltage regulator.

What input voltages do the 2 devices need? Both 5V? If so, you can use a single voltage regulator to power both devices. If one needs 3.3V and the other needs 5V you may have to have 2 different voltage regulators.

By using a switching regulator you can bypass the fairly inefficient linear regulator in your Arduino supply 3.3V or 5V to it directly (depending on the type of board you have.)

### Edit:

Ok, I looked it up and a DFPlayer Mini player appears to be a shield designed to plug directly into an Arduino. It looks like it can be powered from 3.2 to 5V, so you should be able to use it with either a 3.3V or 5V Arduino Pro Mini. Once you've decided if you're going to use a 3.3V or 5V Arduino, pick a buck/boost voltage regulator with the desired output voltage (or get an adjustable one and set it appropriately.)